# Can someone help fix my while loop? It keeps running forever

Tags: c

I am trying to run the code below, but I'm entering a loop I can't get out.

The error message supposed to appear then the user is suppose to be able to enter the correct range value.

Can someone fix this endless loop so that it only appears when the use enters a value out of range please.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int students, counter, total;
    int marks[40];
    int stdno[40];
    total = 0;  

    printf("       ---=== IPC mark Analyser V2.0 ===---\n");
    printf("Please enter the number of students(between 3 and 40):");
    scanf("%d", &students);

    while (students < 3 || students >40) {
        printf("Invalid number, enter a number between 3 and 40 inclusive:");
        scanf("%d", &students);
    }

    printf("Row   Std No  Mrk\n");
    printf("--- --------- ---\n");

    for (counter = 0; counter < students; counter++) {
        printf("    _________ ___\r");
        printf("%03d ", counter + 1);
        scanf("%09d %3d", &stdno[counter], &marks[counter]);

        while (marks < 0 || marks >100 || stdno < 10000000 || stdno > 999999999) {
            printf("Error: Enter values between 0 and 100 inclusive.\n");
            scanf("%09d %3d", &stdno[counter], &marks[counter]);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly first.

Comment: Your code is too poorly formatted for me to bother reading the question.

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled, read the warnings the compiler spits out and treat them as errors.

Comment: Hint: this line has a serious problem: `while (marks < 0 || marks >100 || stdno < 10000000 || stdno > 999999999)`. Finding the problem is left as an exercice to the reader.

Comment: By having a correct indentation, and using auto indent of your IDE, you will find easily your mistake.

Comment: check the while loop inside the for loop, at the end. The condition is poorly written and you are also missing the brackets to the while loop ( I assume you aim to print AND scan once you encounter the condition of the while loop)

Answer (score 2):

1. First the wile loop condition that you have `while (marks < 0 || marks >100 || stdno < 10000000 || stdno > 999999999)` is not correct. `marks` and `stdno` are arrays and cannot be compared to numbers. You even get a compiler warning for that. What you need to do, is to compare to the array element `marks[counter]` and `stdno[counter]`. This is so that each value that you enter in the loop is checked against the condition.
2. The while loop should run over two statements, the `printf` and `scanf`. In your current code, the while loop will just execute the `printf` every time. You need to have braces `{` around the two statements.

   ```
   while (marks[counter] < 0 || marks[counter] >100 || stdno[counter] < 100000000 || stdno[counter] > 999999999)
   {
       printf("Error: Enter values between 0 and 100 inclusive.\n");
       scanf("%09d %3d", &stdno[counter], &marks[counter]);
   }
   ```

You can further improve this by printing the same number above to give an indication to the user.

```
while (marks[counter] < 0 || marks[counter] >100 || stdno[counter] < 100000000 || stdno[counter] > 999999999)
{
    printf("Error: Enter values between 0 and 100 inclusive.\n");
    printf("    _________ __\r");
    printf("%03d ", counter + 1);
    scanf("%09d %3d", &stdno[counter], &marks[counter]);
}
```